# Requiring A9 for 6DOF tracking in ARKit

Tags: ios, arkit

I'm developing an iOS game using ARKit. The game concept only works if [6DOF tracking](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingsessionconfiguration) is available, which means that an *A9* chip or newer is available.

I don't want users to install the game on older devices like an iPhone 6 - on these devices ARKit would fallback to 3DOF tracking, which doesn't make sense for my game concept (I need translation tracking).

How can I enforce this restriction, that the app can only be installed on devices supporting 6DOF (which, to my knowledge is equivalent to *iPhone 6S* or newer or *iPad Pro* or newer, or *A9* or newer)?

I checked the [iOS Device Compatibility Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html) and the [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3) but did not find anything suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be in the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities Reference yet, but as mentioned in the [WWDC talk on ARKit](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc17/602) there is a  UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key: using `arkit` in there ensures that your app is offered only to devices with 6DOF support.

Also, to clarify your list: 6DOF supported devices, aka A9 (and better) devices include...

- iPhone 6s and later
- iPhone SE
- any iPad Pro
- iPad 5th gen (just "iPad", but the one introduced April 2017)